# How to implement if, else statement in CanExecute command or Delegate command in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, prism, delegatecommand

I'm new to `WPF` and `Prism`. How do I use an if else statement when using `CommandCanExecute()`, `CommandExecute()`/Delegate commands?

I have a code to load and get the instance of livechart. However, if the file for the chart does not exist in the users desktop, my application will crash. 
I want to implement a if else statement to say if you cannot find the graph, show up a message box notifying that there is an error, instead of crashing the program.

I tried searching up on RaiseCanExecuteChanged but unsure how to implement.

```
   private bool BEYieldCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void BEYieldCommandExecute() 

    {
        if (true)
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<GraphPubSubEvent>().Publish(_viewName);

        }

        else
        {//Check
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading. Please ensure Excel file/Server file exist in Desktop/Server to generate Chart.", "Invalid Request", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

Thanks alot!!

Comment: The CanExecute method should return a value that indicates whether the command can safely be executed or not. If it returns false, the command won't be executed, i.e. the Execute method won't be called at all.

Comment: @Clemens that's only partially true - the execute method has to check the condition itself (again) to be on the safe side. The command itself will happily call the execute delegate no matter what can execute would return or has returned.

Comment: When CanExecute had returned false, a Button (for example) that is bound to the Command will be disabled. It won't execute the command. There are of course scenarios where logic is more complicated then this, but certainly not in the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML: `<Button Command="{Binding OpenDialogCommand }" />`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand OpenDialogCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenDialogCommand = new DelegateCommand(BrowseFile);
    }

    private void BrowseFile()
    {
        var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Title = "Choose File",
            // TODO: etc v.v
        };
        openDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (File.Exists(openDialog.FileName))
        {
            // TODO: Code logic is here


        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Code logic is here
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You should be more precise. I dont know exacly what you mean. If you have this chart in some file do it like that:

Add this reference on top:

```
using System.IO;
```

then in your code check if file exist:

```
if (!File.Exists("someFile.txt"))
{
CreateFile("someFile.txt");
}
else
{
DoSomeActionWithFile("someFile.txt")
}
```

Another way to do that is block try-catch

```
try
{
OpenFile("someFile.txt");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
LogError(ex.toString());
DoSomethingWithInErrorCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ICommand` implementations are meant to be built as bindable commands 
DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChange() is to refresh if the button is enabled in the UI.
It is not intended to be used in logic behind the commands.

For Example:
XAML Save Button Binding `<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />`

ViewModel Command where the button is only enabled if the Record needs to be saved

```
    private DelegateCommand _saveCommand;
    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand =>
        _saveCommand ?? (_saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSaveCommand, CanExecuteSaveCommand));

    void ExecuteSaveCommand()
    {
        // Save logic goes here
    }

    private bool CanExecuteSaveCommand()
    {
        var isDirty = CurrentRecord.GetIsDirty();
        return isDirty;
    }
```

When the UI is bound the SaveCommand CanExecuteSaveCommand() method is run and let's assume the record is NOT dirty when loaded.
The trick is to wire up an event so when MyRecord is updated the UI button is enabled by calling _saveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged

```
    public MainWindowViewModel(IRecordDataService dataService)
    {
        CurrentRecord = dataService.GetRecord();
        CurrentRecord.Updated += (sender, args) => _saveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this in the command it self.
When you bind the command to a button, the button shall not be enabled when you can't perform the task.

```
bool CanExecute()
{
    return File.Exists("some/path/to/file.ext");
}
```

Additionally, you should add a message to the UI (e.g. next to the button, or as a tool-tip) which is only visible if the button is disabled.